# Prolog argument matching on predicate

Tags: indexing, syntax, prolog, arguments

I'm following the http://www.learnprolognow.org tutorial, and found a solution to exercise 2.4 (http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse7) that puzzled me:

```
word(astante, a,s,t,a,n,t,e).
word(astoria, a,s,t,o,r,i,a).
word(baratto, b,a,r,a,t,t,o).
word(cobalto, c,o,b,a,l,t,o).
word(pistola, p,i,s,t,o,l,a).
word(statale, s,t,a,t,a,l,e).

crossword(V1,V2,V3, H1,H2,H3) :- 
    word(V1, _,V1H1,_,V1H2,_,V1H3,_),
    word(V2, _,V2H1,_,V2H2,_,V2H3,_),
    word(V3, _,V3H1,_,V3H2,_,V3H3,_),
    word(H1, _,V1H1,_,V2H1,_,V3H1,_),
    word(H2, _,V1H2,_,V2H2,_,V3H2,_),
    word(H3, _,V1H3,_,V2H3,_,V3H3,_),
    H1\=V1, H2\=V2, H3\=V3.
```

Given 6 words, we must find possible arrangements of the crossword grid depending on the choice of the vertical an horizontal words (`Vx/Hx`).

For what I can understand, the multiple `word` queries inside the crossword predicate perform some kind of indexing+matching on the non anonymous arguments, which represent crossings on the grid where two words must share a letter.

So far in the tutorial, that syntax has not appeared. I searched online extensively, with no avail.

How does this work?

I ran some queries trying to mimic the behavior, but Prolog interprets `V1H1` not as in the example, but as a new variable.

I was hoping someone could shed some light on the matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "So far in the tutorial, that syntax has not appeared": what syntax do you mean, exactly?

Comment: *I ran some queries trying to mimic the behavior*. Can you give an example of a query that didn't give you the result you expected? Prolog will run a query attempting to match it with either a fact or the head of another predicate by instantiating the variables given.

Comment: @lurker I was guessing that he tried calling the subgoals one after the other in separate queries.

Comment: @Boris, using two variables, one after the other, in the place of a single argument. Like: word(V1, _,V1H1,_,V1H2,_,V1H3,_). So far, every query/definition has a variable or a complex term as arguments, but not something like V1H1.

Comment: @lurker, tried something like word(X, Y, XY) (with a diferent definition of word, that is), hoping the third argument will have X = Y as a requisite for unification. Still, the interpreter just gives me possible matches for the new variable XY, independently of X or Y.

Comment: These are not two variables at all: this is just a variable called `V1H1`. You will see, for example, that `V1H1` appears in the first and the fourth call to `word/4`. The names could have been anything, but these names are supposed to be descriptive ("vertical 1, horizontal 1"). Try something: after loading this program, run the query `?- listing(crossword).` You will see that all variables have been renamed, and the HxVx has no importance.

Comment: @Boris, I get it now, don't know what I was thinking. Need to sleep before programming, I never learn that, Thanks for the explanation.